# Set timer for a gif to start

Tags: css, animation, timer, mouseover, gif

I have a .gif that is animated to begin from the left of the screen to a few hundred pixels to the right. The animation lasts 5 seconds and I have set it so it doesn't return to its initial spot.

What I want is for the .gif to start once the CSS animation is finished. I realise that some forums give codes for a mouseover effect so that it changes from a .jpg source of the animation to the .gif. But I can't find anything that gives you a timer instead of mouseover.

It's been a few years since I've worked on websites and I've forgotten so much, so this has been a struggle.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change an `<img>` source via javascript is fairly simple, the syntax looks like `img.src = "new/source.gif"`.

Having the change to a GIF match up with the end of your animation can be achieved a variety of ways, but I would do it by adding the animation to your element as a class at the same time you set a time out in your javascript.

**HTML**

```
<img id="image" src="path/to/static.jpg">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var img = document.getElementById("image");

function photoSwitch(){

    // begin your CSS animation by applying class
    img.setAttribute("class", "some-animation");

    // have javascript wait 5s before switching the image source
    setTimeout(function(){
        img.src = "path/to/moving.gif";
    },5000);
}

photoSwitch();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm pretty sure I got everything right, but not sure what I am meant to add in "some-animation". Thanks!

Comment: Nvm, all I was doing wrong was just pasting the <script src link to the javascript in the head of the html instead of the body haha. Sigh...like i said it's been a while. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ko24be glad this helped you! If this answer worked for you, you can mark it as accepted with the checkmark underneath the voting arrows.